# Prime to Prime: Get all first 25 Prime Numbers using up to 4 Primes

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, primes

The first 25 Prime Numbers are

> 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97

Using up to 4 prime numbers and the following mathematical operations, get all the 25 primes.

> **+ - x / ^ √ !**

No other operators (like **!!**) are allowed.

### Other rules

- You cannot use same Prime Number more than once.
- You can use only Prime Numbers.
- Any number that appears as a number in the equation will be counted as one of the primes out of four (e.g. 7^2 means you have used both 7 and 2).
- You do not have to use all the 4 primes in every equation.
- You must use the **SAME** 4 primes in every equation. If you select say 2, 13, 17, 23 then they are the only primes that to appear in every equation to get the 25 primes.

I have 1 solution. There may be more.

No programming please.
NO PARTIAL ANSWERS.

Comment: No partial answers... why? This seems like an exercise in tedium

Comment: Because there will be so many partial answers. If someone gets say 5 equations they will post an answer.

Comment: Are parentheses allowed?

Comment: Yes they are of course

Comment: Not sure why that is "of course". maybe you should mention it in the description. Also is concatination allowed?

Comment: Are you essentially asking us to do what computers are made to do, but manually?

Comment: Thanks for your point  @my pronoun is monicareinstate. However most Math puzzles can be solved by computers. That is why many have no-computer Tag. In this case if you check the answers there is a Pattern and some logic. The difficult numbers are not the smaller ones but numbers like 83, 89. So if one focuses on say top 4 numbers (79 to 97) a commonality emerges reducing total brute force.

Comment: I'm not going to answer, because I used a computer, but there are 145 multisets of primes under 100 which work; if you want a real challenge, try to find the one multiset of primes which works without using any factorials.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. Is there a solution without using a factorial?

Comment: There is exactly one choice of 4 primes under 100 which works without any factorials.

Comment: That would be a great puzzle @Peter Taylor with some interesting clues

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using 2,3,7,11:

> $2 = 2$
>
> $3 = 3$
>
> $5 = 11 + 3 - 7 -2$
>
> $7 = 7$
>
> $11 = 11$
>
> $13 = 2 + 11$
>
> $17 = 3! + 11$
>
> $19 = 2^3 + 11$
>
> $23 = 3 \cdot 7 + 2$
>
> $29 = \frac{(7-2)!}{3} - 11$
>
> $31 = 3 \cdot 11- 2$
>
> $37 = (11-3!) \cdot 7 + 2$
>
> $41 = 7^2 +3 - 11$
>
> $43 = 2 \cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 7$
>
> $47 = 3 \cdot 11 + 2 \cdot 7$
>
> $53 = 2^ {3!} - 11$
>
> $59 = 3! \cdot 11 - 7$
>
> $61 = (11-2) \cdot 3! + 7$
>
> $67 = 7 \cdot 2^3 + 11$
>
> $71 = 2^{3!} + 7$
>
> $73 = 3! \cdot 11 + 7$
>
> $79 = 7 \cdot 11 + 2$
>
> $83 = 7 \cdot 11 + 3!$
>
> $89 = 7 \cdot 11 + 2 \cdot 3!$
>
> $97 = (2+11) \cdot 7 + 3!$

Comment: Well played. I'm giving up hope on my own answer... must keep looking...

Comment: why not simply 5= 2+3 ?

Answer (score 9):

83 is probably not allowed - I swear I'll find a legitimate solution soon... arrgh...

Using 2,3,5,7:

> $2, 3, 5, 7 = 2, 3, 5, 7$
>
> $11 = 7 + 5 + 2 - 3$
>
> $13 = 7 + 5 + 3 - 2$
>
> $17 = 7 \cdot 2 + 3$
>
> $19 = 7 \cdot 2 + 5$
>
> $23 = 7 \cdot 3 + 2$
>
> $29 = 7 \cdot 5 - 3!$
>
> $31 = 7 \cdot 5 - 3! + 2$
>
> $37 = 7 \cdot 5 + 2$
>
> $41 = 7 \cdot 5 + 3!$
>
> $43 = 7 \cdot 5 + 3! + 2$
>
> $47 = 7^2 +3 - 5$
>
> $53 = \frac{5!}{2} - 7$
>
> $59 = \frac{5!}{2} + 3! - 7$
>
> $61 = \frac{5!}{2} + 7 - 3!$
>
> $67 = \frac{5!}{2} + 7$
>
> $71 = 3!^2 + 5 \cdot 7$
>
> $73 = \frac{5!}{2} + 7 + 3!$
>
> $79 = 7 \cdot (3! + 5) + 2$
>
> $83 = 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! - \sqrt[\textbf{...}]{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}}}}$
>
> $89 = 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! + 5$
>
> $97 = 5! - 7 \cdot 3 - 2$

I had to get creative with some of these, but this was easier than expected (except 83) - many patterns seen.

Comment: You need to be exact. 83 is not right. But kudos for getting rest of them

Comment: I assume concatenation is not allowed either, otherwise we can do 83 = 73+2*5

Comment: @DEEM 83 is exact here, due to the _infinite_ number of roots. There was no restriction that the number of operations needs to be finite.

Comment: @trolley813 yeah, that was my original thought.

Comment: @Quintec there is a solution with 2,3,5 and another Prime without infinite roots.

Comment: @ThomasL Yeah, or 5! - 37.

Comment: @Quintec, using excel, I can get rot13{`=SNPGQBHOYR(7)-(2*(SNPG(3)+5))` jurer `SNPG` vf snpgbevny, naq `SNPGQBHOYR` vf qbhoyr snpgbevny (=7!!-(2*(3!+5))) }

Comment: @SeanC double factorial is not allowed

Comment: If squaring could be used like square root (doesn't use your single "2" value), then 5!-(7^2 - (3! x 2)) would get you 83. But really just posting to see if this gets a solve, besides infinite sqrt.

Comment: @DEEM, actually there are nine valid solutions with 2, 3, 5, and another prime.

Comment: @PeterTaylor 1. Anyway you can share what program you used for this testing? 2. Is there a solution for 83 with these 4? (PM to avoid spoilers?)

Answer (score 5):

#### Using 3, 5, 7, 11

2  = 5 - 3
3  = 3
5  = 5
7  = 7
11 = 11
13 = 7 + 3!
17 = 11 + 3!
19 = 3 × 5 + 11 - 7
23 = 11 + 7 + 5
29 = 5!/3 - 11
31 = 11 × 3 + 5 - 7
37 = 7 × 3! - 5
41 = 5 × 3! + 11
43 = 7 × 5 + 11 - 3
47 = 5!/3 + 7
53 = 7!/5! + 11
59 = 11 × 5 + 7 - 3
61 = 11 × 5 + 3!
67 = (3+5) × 7 + 11
71 = 7 × 11 - 3!
73 = 11 × 3! + 7
79 = 11 × 7 + 5 - 3
83 = 11 × 7 + 3!
89 = (11 + 5) × 3! - 7
97 = 11 × 7 + 5!/3!

89 was the hardest of these for me, followed by 67 and 53.