# Prime to number conversion

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, primes

This puzzle relates to  [Prime to Prime: Get all first 25 Prime Numbers using up to 4 Primes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91841/prime-to-prime-get-all-first-25-prime-numbers-using-up-to-4-primes) and its sequel [Prime to Prime Sequel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91891/prime-to-prime-sequel)

> Using any **three of the first 4** prime numbers (2,3,5 and 7) and the
>   folllowing math operations get the first 23 numbers (from 1 to 23).
>
> x / + - ^ ! !! Square root

Other Rules

Once you select the three primes all the three primes must appear (once only) in every equation. Use of only 1 or 2 primes not permitted. All three primes must appear once only. ( e.g.  4=7-3 not allowed. it could be 4=2+7-5)

Same three primes must appear in every equation.

Any prime that appears anywhere in the equation is counted. If you used 3^2 then you have used up 2 and 3

Multiple roots not allowed ( Sq root of sq root)

Concatenation is forbidden.

Parentheses are permitted.

Please no partial answers.

Comment: All three primes must appear only once? But you've given us **four** primes...

Comment: Yes. You can pick any three out of 4 . Those three must appear once in every equation. Say you use 2 , 3 and 5 then only those 3 must be used once in every equation.

Comment: For multiple roots, does that disqualify taking the square root of a square? For example, could I do \sqrt{5^2} ?

Comment: Yes it does @Herb Wolfe

Comment: This is a fun puzzle (I got here a bit late unfortunately). I doubt that allowing multiple roots would create any additional solutions in this case, since rounding isn't allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be more fun to fill the whole table. I've started with a few examples:

$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\def\*{\times }
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 n& 2,3,5           & 2,3,7           & 2,5,7           & 3,5,7           \\
\hline
 1& 2\*3-5          & 7-2\*3          & \frac{2+5}{7}   & 3+5-7           \\
 2& (3!-5)\*2       & 7-3-2           & \sqrt{(7-5)\*2} & \frac{3+7}5     \\
 3& (5-2)!-3        & \frac{7+2}{3}   & 2\*5-7          & \sqrt{3^{7-5}}  \\
 4& 2-3+5           & 2^{\sqrt{7-3}}  & 2-5+7           & \frac{7+5}{3}   \\
 5& (3-2)\*5        & \frac{7+3}{2}   &\frac{7!!}{5!!}-2& 3-5+7           \\
 6& -2+3+5          & 2-3+7           & \frac{7+5}{2}   & (7-5)\*3        \\
 7& 2\*5-3          & (3-2)\*7        & \sqrt{(2+5)\*7} & \sqrt{7^{5-3}}  \\
 8& (\frac{3+5}{2})!!  & -2+3+7       & 5+\sqrt{2+7}    & 3\*5-7          \\
 9& (5-2)!+3        & (7-2)!!-3!      & 2\*7-5          & -3+5+7          \\
10& 2+3+5           & 7+\frac{3!}{2}  & -2+5+7          & 5\*\sqrt{7-3}   \\
11& 2\*3+5          & 2\*7-3          & \frac{5!!+7}{2} & 5!!+3-7         \\
12& (5-2)!+3!       & 2+3+7           & \sqrt{(5+7)^2}  & (7-5)\*3!       \\
13& 2\*5+3          & 2\*3+7          & (5-2)!+7        & {7!!\over5!!}+3!\\
14& 3^2+5           & 2\*\frac{7!}{(3!)!} & 2+5+7      & (5-3)\*7        \\
15& (3-2)\*5!!      & (7-2)\*3        & 5\*\sqrt{2+7}   & 3+5+7           \\
16& (5+3)\*2        & 2^{(7-3)}       & (5!!-7)\*2      & 3\*7-5          \\
17& 3\*5+2          & 2\*7+3          & 2\*5+7          & 5!!+\sqrt{7-3}  \\
18& (5-2)!\*3       & (7-2)!!+3       & 5^2-7           & 3+5!-7!!        \\
19& 5!!+3!-2        & 3\*7-2          & 2\*7+5          & 5!!+7-3         \\
20& 5!!+3+2         & 2\*(3+7)        & 5!!+7-2         & (7-3)\*5        \\
21& (5+2)\*3        & (7-2)!!+3!      & 7\*(5-2)        & 3*{7!!\over5!!} \\
22& 5^2-3           & (7-3)!-2        &                 & 3\*5+7          \\
23& 5!!+3!+2        & 3\*7+2          & 5!!\*2-7        & 5!!+(7-3)!!     \\
\hline
\end{array}
\endgroup$$

Comment: Wow. OK. I did that but for me it did not work with all combinations. Only one. May be you will have better approach

Comment: 2, 3, 5 is done

Comment: Of course, now that @David G. has generated a complete chart, the challenge for new entries here is to differ from that chart

Comment: 2, 3, 7 is complete now as well.

Comment: Added a couple more

Comment: @eyl327 I found those, and a couple of others as well (237 ->11 & 357->18), but they are the same as the ones in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97884/17297, so I've held off on adding them

Comment: The 2 formed by 2,5,7 uses a 6 instead of a 2. The answer of @DavidG. has a replacement for that, but now we take into account what humn just said.

Comment: @oAlt; I've fixed 257:2

Comment: @JMP  Hard Question. Is there any possible answer without using !!

Comment: @DEEM; I doubt it - the options just run out. If you had allowed $!!!$, we cojuld have $7!!!-(5-2)!=22$ and $7!!!-5!!-2=11$, but multi-factorials allow practically everything in.

Comment: @JMP I found an 2,5,7 -> 11 example that doesn't require !!!.  Added it.  Edit: Oh, never mind, David G found it first.  Whatever, it's added.

Answer (score 8):

I tried writing a generator.  I can get everything from 1 to 24 inclusive, for all 4 combinations.  I can get 0 to 33 for one combination.  The first ungeneratable counting number is 68.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& 2,3,5 & 2,3,7 & 2,5,7 & 3,5,7 \\
\hline
0 & (5-(2+3)) & (3-\sqrt{(2+7)}) & (7-(2+5)) & - \\
1 & (\frac{5}{(2+3)}) & (7-(2\times3)) & (\frac{7}{(2+5)}) & ((3+5)-7) \\
2 & \sqrt{(5+(2-3))} & (7-(2+3)) & \sqrt{(7+(2-5))} & (\frac{(3+7)}{5}) \\
3 & ({2}^{3}-5) & (\frac{(2+7)}{3}) & ((2\times5)-7) & \sqrt{(7-(3-5))} \\
4 & (5+(2-3)) & \sqrt{(7+{3}^{2})} & (7+(2-5)) & (\frac{(5+7)}{3}) \\
5 & (5\times(3-2)) & (\frac{(3+7)}{2}) & \sqrt{({2}^{5}-7)} & (7+(3-5)) \\
6 & (5-(2-3)) & (7+(2-3)) & (\frac{(5+7)}{2}) & (3\times(7-5)) \\
7 & ((2\times5)-3) & (7\times(3-2)) & \sqrt{(7\times(2+5))} & (\frac{{7}!!}{(3\times5)}) \\
8 & (\frac{{5}!}{{(2+3)}!!}) & (7-(2-3)) & {(7+(2-5))}!! & ((3\times5)-7) \\
9 & (3\times(5-2)) & (3\times\sqrt{(2+7)}) & ((2\times7)-5) & (7-(3-5)) \\
10 & (5+(2+3)) & \sqrt{({7}!!-(2+3))} & (7-(2-5)) & (5\times\sqrt{(7-3)}) \\
11 & (5+(2\times3)) & ((2\times7)-3) & (\frac{({5}!!+7)}{2}) & ({5}!!+(3-7)) \\
12 & \sqrt{(\frac{{(2\times3)}!}{5})} & (7+(2+3)) & ({5}!!-\sqrt{(2+7)}) & (\frac{{5}!}{(3+7)}) \\
13 & (5+{2}^{3}) & (7+(2\times3)) & (7+{(5-2)}!) & (5+{(7-3)}!!) \\
14 & (5+{3}^{2}) & (7\times\sqrt{({3}!-2)}) & (7+(2+5)) & (7\times(5-3)) \\
15 & \sqrt{({5}!!\times{(2+3)}!!)} & (7+{2}^{3}) & (\frac{{(2+5)}!!}{7}) & (7+(3+5)) \\
16 & (2\times(3+5)) & (7+{3}^{2}) & (2\times({5}!!-7)) & ((3\times7)-5) \\
17 & (2+(3\times5)) & (3+(2\times7)) & (7+(2\times5)) & ({5}!!+\sqrt{(7-3)}) \\
18 & ({5}!!+\sqrt{{3}^{2}}) & ({3}!\times\sqrt{(2+7)}) & ({5}^{2}-7) & ({3}!+(5+7)) \\
19 & ({5}^{2}-{3}!) & ((3\times7)-2) & (5+(2\times7)) & ({5}!!-(3-7)) \\
20 & (5+{(2+3)}!!) & (2\times(3+7)) & ({5}!!-(2-7)) & (5\times(7-3)) \\
21 & (3\times(2+5)) & (\frac{{7}!!}{(2+3)}) & (7\times(5-2)) & (\frac{(3\times{7}!!)}{{5}!!}) \\
22 & ({5}^{2}-3) & (7+{(2+3)}!!) & ({5}!!+\sqrt{{7}^{2}}) & (7+(3\times5)) \\
23 & ({5}!!+{2}^{3}) & (2+(3\times7)) & (2+(\frac{{7}!!}{5})) & ({5}!!+{(7-3)}!!) \\
24 & (\frac{{(2+3)}!}{5}) & {(7-\sqrt{{3}^{2}})}! & (2\times(5+7)) & {(\frac{(5+7)}{3})}! \\
25 & (5\times(2+3)) & - & ({2}^{5}-7) & ({5}!!+(3+7)) \\
26 & ({2}^{5}-{3}!) & (2+{(7-3)}!) & - & (5+(3\times7)) \\
27 & {3}^{(5-2)} & (3\times(2+7)) & - & ({3}!+(\frac{{7}!!}{5})) \\
28 & (3+{5}^{2}) & (7\times({3}!-2)) & - & ({3}!+({5}!!+7)) \\
29 & ({2}^{5}-3) & ({{3}!}^{2}-7) & ({5}!!+(2\times7)) & ((5\times7)-{3}!) \\
30 & (5\times(2\times3)) & ({3}!\times(7-2)) & ({5}!!+{(7-2)}!!) & (\frac{{5}!}{(7-3)}) \\
31 & ({3}!+{5}^{2}) & (7+{({3}!-2)}!) & - & - \\
32 & {2}^{(\frac{{5}!!}{3})} & \sqrt{{2}^{(3+7)}} & (7+{5}^{2}) & ((5\times7)-3) \\
33 & ({(2\times3)}!!-{5}!!) & ((\frac{{7}!!}{3})-2) & ((5\times7)-2) & ((\frac{{5}!}{3})-7) \\
34 & - & ({({3}!)}!!-(2\times7)) & ({7}^{2}-{5}!!) & - \\
35 & (3+{2}^{5}) & (7\times(2+3)) & (\frac{{7}!!}{(5-2)}) & (\frac{{5}!!}{(\frac{3}{7})}) \\
36 & ({3}!\times{(5-2)}!) & - & - & (3\times(5+7)) \\
37 & - & (2+(\frac{{7}!!}{3})) & (2+(5\times7)) & (7+({3}!\times5)) \\
38 & ({3}!+{2}^{5}) & - & - & (3+(5\times7)) \\
39 & (3\times({5}!!-2)) & ({({3}!)}!!-(2+7)) & (7+{2}^{5}) & ({5}!!+{(7-3)}!) \\
40 & (5\times{2}^{3}) & (\frac{{(7-2)}!}{3}) & (\frac{{5}!}{\sqrt{(2+7)}}) & (5\times{(7-3)}!!) \\
41 & ({({3}!)}!!-(2+5)) & ({(2\times3)}!!-7) & - & ({3}!+(5\times7)) \\
42 & ({3}!\times(2+5)) & (7\times(2\times3)) & ({7}!!\times(\frac{2}{5})) & (\frac{{7}!}{{(\frac{{5}!!}{3})}!}) \\
43 & ({(2\times3)}!!-5) & ({7}^{2}-{3}!) & - & - \\
44 & - & (2+({3}!\times7)) & ({7}^{2}-5) & - \\
45 & (5\times{3}^{2}) & (3\times{(7-2)}!!) & (5\times(2+7)) & (3+(\frac{{7}!}{{5}!})) \\
46 & - & ({7}^{2}-3) & - & ({({3}!)}!!+(5-7)) \\
47 & (2+(3\times{5}!!)) & - & - & (7+(\frac{{5}!}{3})) \\
48 & {(5-(2-3))}!! & {(7+(2-3))}!! & (\frac{{7}!}{{(2+5)}!!}) & {((3\times7)-{5}!!)}!! \\
49 & ({2}^{{3}!}-{5}!!) & \sqrt{{7}^{({3}!-2)}} & (7\times(2+5)) & {7}^{(5-3)} \\
50 & - & - & (\frac{({7}!!-5)}{2}) & (5\times(3+7)) \\
51 & (3\times(2+{5}!!)) & (\frac{({7}!!-3)}{2}) & - & - \\
52 & - & (3+{7}^{2}) & - & (7+(3\times{5}!!)) \\
53 & (5+{(2\times3)}!!) & ({({3}!)}!!-(2-7)) & ((\frac{{5}!}{2})-7) & - \\
54 & ((\frac{{5}!}{2})-{3}!) & ({3}!\times(2+7)) & (5+{7}^{2}) & - \\
55 & ({({3}!)}!!+(2+5)) & (7+{(2\times3)}!!) & (\frac{(5+{7}!!)}{2}) & ({({3}!)}!!+(\frac{{7}!!}{{5}!!})) \\
56 & ({5}!-{2}^{{3}!}) & (7\times{2}^{3}) & - & (7\times(3+5)) \\
57 & ((\frac{{5}!}{2})-3) & ({7}!!-{(2\times3)}!!) & - & ({5}!!+({3}!\times7)) \\
58 & ({({3}!)}!!+(2\times5)) & - & - & ({({3}!)}!!+\sqrt{({7}!!-5)}) \\
59 & ({2}^{{3}!}-5) & ((2+{7}!!)-{({3}!)}!!) & - & - \\
60 & \sqrt{(5\times{(2\times3)}!)} & \sqrt{({({3}!)}!\times(7-2))} & (\frac{({5}!!+{7}!!)}{2}) & (\frac{{5}!}{\sqrt{(7-3)}}) \\
61 & ({({3}!)}!!-(2-{5}!!)) & - & - & - \\
62 & - & ({({3}!)}!!+(2\times7)) & - & ((5+{7}!!)-{({3}!)}!!) \\
63 & ({5}!!+{(2\times3)}!!) & (7\times{3}^{2}) & (\frac{{(2+7)}!!}{{5}!!}) & ({7}!!\times(\frac{3}{5})) \\
64 & {(3+5)}^{2} & {{(7-3)}!!}^{2} & \sqrt{{2}^{(5+7)}} & {(5-7)}^{{3}!} \\
65 & ({({3}!)}!!+(2+{5}!!)) & - & - & ({7}!!-(\frac{{5}!}{3})) \\
66 & ({3}!+(\frac{{5}!}{2})) & - & - & (3\times({5}!!+7)) \\
67 & - & - & (7+(\frac{{5}!}{2})) & - \\
68 & - & - & - & - \\
69 & (5+{2}^{{3}!}) & ({7}!!-{{3}!}^{2}) & - & ({({3}!)}!!+(\frac{{7}!!}{5})) \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Edit: Line Break issue (that someone else also noticed).
Corrected ${{3}!}!!$ to ${{(3}!)}!!$ and ${{3}!}!$ to ${{(3}!)}!$.  (The mathjax source is OK, but it doesn't combine right.)

Comment: Ah I was just about to try this when I saw your answer. +1

Comment: Impressive... even if some items are disqualified as per author's comment (e.g. 22 with 2,5,7)

Comment: @David G.  Are there any answers if we do not use !! double factorial?